# How to disable password/confirmation validations when using has_secure_password in Rails 3.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a user model set up as such:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password

  # callbacks -------------------------------------------------------------------------
  before_create { generate_token(:auth_token) }

  # setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model and validation ----------
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation

  # validations
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email    , presence: true,
                        uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false },
                        format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }

  validates :password             , length: { minimum: 6 } 

  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true
```

But I don't want the password and/or password_confirmation validations to run when updating the user *unless* the user is attempting to change their password.

So, if the user updates their information in a form without specifying a password and/or confirmation it should succeed.  If the user updates their information and includes a password and/or confirmation the validations *should* run.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: You can also update attributes using @user.update_attributes({}) or @user.update_attribute :attr_name, value.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could add a conditional `:if` to both validators:

Option 1:

```
validates :password             , length: { minimum: 6 }, :if => :validate_password?
validates :password_confirmation, presence: true        , :if => :validate_password?

def validate_password?
  password.present? || password_confirmation.present?
end
```

Option 2:

Or use a method for validation, moving the validation checks into the method instead of as separate `validates` calls:

```
validate :check_password, :on => :update

def check_password
  return unless password.present? || password_confirmation.present?
  ..validations for both attributes here.. 
  ..check presence, length etc. as required and add to the errors variable as necessary..
end
```

Comment: option 1 nice, just what I needed. But "password_validation" should be "password_confirmation".

Comment: !password.nil? is better then .present?, else signing up without password is possible

Comment: `.present?` returns `true` if the string is `nil?` or `blank?`, so it ensures that the string contains one or more characters apart from spaces.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Zabba's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9756840/1765500), option 1 could also be written like this:

```
with_options if: :password_provided? do
    validates :password, :password_confirmation, presence: true, length: { minimum: 12 }
end

def password_provided?
    password.present? || password_confirmation.present?
end
```