# Rails state_machine transition causes password validation error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passwords, ruby-on-rails-plugins, railstutorial.org

I've been following Michael Hartl's rails tutorial and have been tackling the extension he suggests in [Signup confirmation](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/following-users#sec-signup_confirmation) to get users to click on an emailed link to activate their account. To manage the activation I'm using the state_machine gem but when I try to activate a user account I get an error "Cannot transition state via :activate from :pending (Reason(s): Password is too short (minimum is 6 characters))". 
To me it seems as if the database operation which state_machine is implementing to update the state field is somehow causing validation associated with the user record (possibly associated with the has_secure_password method) to be triggered and to fail.
I did come across another stackoverflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14070621/applying-validation-exception-when-using-state-machine) on the topic a year ago, but reading the comments on that question there didn't seem to be a resolution.

My user model (user.rb) code is below (it's basically the tutorial code in listing 6.29 plus the addition of a state machine). [Sorry, can't provide a link as stackoverflow is not allowing me more than 2 links!]

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 } 
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, 
    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  before_save { email.downcase! }
  validates :password, length: { minimum: 6, maximum: 50 }
  has_secure_password
  before_create :create_remember_token

  state_machine initial: :pending do
    state :pending, value: 0
    state :active, value: 1

    event :activate do
      transition :pending => :active
    end

    event :deactivate do
      transition :active => :pending
    end 
  end

  def initialize
    super()
  end
```

My database user table structure is:

```
create_table "users", force: true do |t|
t.string   "name"
t.string   "email"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
t.string   "password_digest"
t.string   "remember_token"
t.boolean  "admin",           default: false
t.string   "token"
t.integer  "state"
end
```

In the rails console the state_machine code seems to be interpreting the values in the database ok, because I can get a user record and when I do user.can_activate? and user.can_deactivate? it's returning me what I expect. But when I try to do user.activate! or user.deactivate! I get the password too short error. Any suggestions as to how to address this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to this through changing the code to dispense with state_machine and update the state field in the database directly. I then discovered that *all* updates of the user record were causing the password validation to trigger and the password length error to appear (hence not a problem with state_machine).
As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9756652/how-to-disable-password-confirmation-validations-when-using-has-secure-password) the solution is to prevent the password validation from occurring if the password is not one of the attributes being updated by changing the "validates" line above to:

```
validates :password, length: { minimum: 6, maximum: 50 }, :if => :validate_password?
def validate_password?
  password.present? || password_confirmation.present?
end
```

Once that is changed the state_machine functionality works fine.